# How to define enum type in Angular to not violating tslint typedef rule

Tags: angular, typescript, lint, tslint

To be able to use enumerations in template, we write below codes in ts file.

in workflowProgress.ts

```
export enum WorkflowProgress
{
    cancelled = 0,
    inProgress,
    done
}
```

in component.ts

```
export class Component {
   WorkflowProgress = WorkflowProgress;
   x : WorkflowProgress = WorkflowProgress.done;
}
```

in template.html

```
<div *ngIf="x === WorkflowProgress.done">
```

and we already have tslint with typedef rule enabled. but tslint is nagging about this line `WorkflowProgress = WorkflowProgress;`

> [tslint] expected member-variable-declaration: 'WorkflowProgress' to have a typedef (typedef)

I can disable the rule for by adding `// tslint:disable-next-line:typedef` but I was wondering if there is better way to do it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `typeof` operator to "query" the type of enum:

```
WorkflowProgress: typeof WorkflowProgress = WorkflowProgress
```